# C++ #include and #import difference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, import, include

What is the difference between `#include` and `#import` in C++?

Comment: Note `#import` for vc++ and gcc is different from `import` of C++20.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`#import` is a Microsoft-specific thing, apparently for COM or .NET stuff only.

`#include` is a standard C/C++ preprocessor statement, used for including header (or occasionally other source code) files in your source code file.

Comment: This is not true.  The #import directive was officially undeprecated by the gcc team in version 3.4 and works fine 99% of the time in all previous versions of gcc which support

Comment: Curious, I wasn't aware of that. Perhaps I should have said it's a COM- and .NET-specific thing instead.

Comment: The #import supported by gcc is a nonportable way to include a header once only: <a href="http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/cpp/Obsolete-once_002donly-headers.html"/>.  It is completely unrelated to the Microsoft COM #import.

Comment: The GCC #import is actually an Objective-C preprocessor command that happens to work with .c files in gcc and clang(except in pedantic mode).

Comment: import is actually pretty clever; dlls can export the headers as a text string that can be loaded on any platform(granted the dll needs to be recompiled) before compiling the c code, and paste the string into the source code before compilation; effectively eliminating the need for header files altogether. I think this was part of the technology that allowed java and other dynamic languages not to have header files, but still have type awareness(Granted they tend to compress the type info rather than keep it as string).

Comment: Fixed link: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/cpp/Obsolete-once_002donly-headers.html

Answer (score 95):

**Import in VC++:**  `#import` is for type libraries or .tlbs (COM stuff).

The content of the type library is converted into C++ classes, mostly describing the COM interfaces for you automatically, and then it is included into your file.

The `#import` directive was introduced by Microsoft as an extension to the C++ language.  You can read about it at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx).

The `#import` directive is also used with .NET / CLI stuff.

**Import in gcc:**
The import in gcc is different from the import in VC++. It is a simple way to include a header at most once only.  (In VC++ and GCC you can do this via `#pragma` once as well)

The `#import` directive was officially undeprecated by the gcc team in version 3.4 and works fine 99% of the time in all previous versions of gcc which support

**Include:**  `#include` is for mostly header files, but to prepend the content to your current file. `#include` is part of the C++ standard.  You can read about it at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx).

Comment: Your MSDN links are stale. Thanks Microsoft.

Answer (score 11):

`#import` is overall a *solution* to the usual

```
#ifndef ...
#define ...
#include ...
#endif
```

work-around. `#import` includes a file only if it hasn't been included before.

It might be worth noting that Apple's Objective-C also uses `#import` statements.

Answer (score 6):

Should this post be updated?

Now, since the C++20 standard is outta there, we can get into scope "modules" with the `import` statement.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules

In terms of compiling speed when multiple modules are called from different parts of the code, import statement seems to be quicker than the old `#include` preprocesor directive.

Comment: c++20 import is completely irrelevant because beginning with preprocessor character '#' indicating it is a preprocessor directive, whiles module "import" is a keyword starting with a module delcaration.

Comment: import completly irrelevant? LMAO. Can you defend your answer to SO readers instead just "telling people" obvious things like **what is a preprocesor directive**?

Comment: I think the distinction @NickHuang is trying to draw is between `#import` and `import`. This question is re: the MS `#import` statement and specifically relates to `visual-c++` as in the tags. The `import` keyword is a newish concept and didn't exist (in the standard) when this question was asked.

Comment: I believe whoever search for `#include` and `import` would find this question in the first place as well. So it's relevant because of the limitation of search engine.

Comment: @LouisGo This is true. This question is a top 1 in Google's "C++ import" search results. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

*import* was also one of the keywords associated with [n2073, Modules in C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2073.pdf#search=%22n2073%20c%2B%2B%22), proposed to the language committee by Daveed Vandevoorde in September 2006. I'm not enough of a language geek to know if that proposal was definitively shelved or if it's awaiting an implementation (proof of concept) from the author or someone else...

Comment: Daveed was an EDG employee at the time, so I'd expect them to have so working code.

Comment: I sure hope they've done the requisite legwork, because it would be very nice to move from '#include' to an import mechanism. But I've heard nary a peep on this feature, and I'm pretty sure it's not in C++0X. Maybe sometime before I retire ;^)~

Comment: As I feared, it's a few years out:

[Modules in C++09?](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/5ce3042a8de03284?dmode=source)

Answer (score 4):

Please note that in gcc 4.1, `#import` *is* deprecated.  If you use it, you will get warning:

> `#import` is a deprecated GCC extension

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.