# What is the difference between #import and #include in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ include and import difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172262/c-include-and-import-difference)

Can someone explain the difference and where may I use one versus the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172262/c-include-and-import-difference

Comment: the first does not exists, the second performs copy-pasting of the file given to it.

Answer (score 6):

- `#include` includes a file in the current compilation unit.
- `#import` does not exist in the C++ standard.

This answer was true in '14. However, the C++ standard has evolved since then and `import` now exists. Without the `#`.

Comment: Bad answer, wrongly upvoted.  import DOES exist in C++20

Comment: Don't want to nitpick, but `#import` still does not exist in the C++20 standard. Only `import` does. Thanks anyway, I've added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

- `#import` imports information (types, functions, variables etc) from .lib file. It's non-standard directive.
- `#include` includes header file.

See these topics:

- [#import Directive (C/C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [#include Directive (C/C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`#include` cause the referenced file to be "copy-and-pasted" at the current position during the preprocessing phase.

`#import` is not in the `C++` standard, but is an extension provided by some compiler. There is no consensus about what it does. For GCC, it is equivalent to `#include` but try to ensure that the file has not already been included. For MSVC, it may have another meaning.

It is best to avoid `#import` (sadly) if you want to write code portable to multiple compilers.