# What is the difference between int &r=x and r=y in C++?

Tags: c++, reference

```
#import<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //trying to test pointers & reference
    int x = 5;
    int y = 6;
    int *p;
    p = &y;
    *p = 10;
    int &r = x;
    cout<<"X reference\n"<<&r<<"\n"<<"value:"<<r<<"\n";
    r=y;
    cout<<"Y reference\n"<<&r<<"\n"<<"value:"<<r<<"\n";
}
```

In this code, I have assigned &r to x at first and then I have assigned r to y.

1. What is the difference between assigning & r=x and r=y?
   Kindly help me out.

Comment: You can't reseat references. That's the difference. And why is there `import` in your code?

Comment: Try also printing out `x` and `y` at the end of the program.

Comment: r is alias to x. `&r = x` initializes the reference to be alias to x. Since r is alias to x now, `r=y` is same as `x=y`.

Comment: @remyabel #import is a [Microsoft specific preprocessor directive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/172274/2705293).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int &r = x;`

defines a reference to int variable.

References cannot change what they reference after they are defined, so the line

`r=y;`

is assigning `x` the value that is stored in `y`. It does not make `r` start referencing `y`. Any assignment to or from `r` will be treated as if it was from `x`.

Another way to think about references is as if they are a pointer variable which you cannot change what is pointed to after it is initialized and any occurrence of their usage has an implicit dereference (`*`) operator.

Answer (score 0):

`int& r = x` declares a reference to `x`, think about it as an alias. So if you further down the line modify `x`, it will be reflected in `r`, for example,

```
x = 10;
cout << r; // r is "updated" here, as it is a reference to `x`
```

will print `10`.

On the other hand, the declaration `int r = x` just copies the value of `x` into `r`, then `r` is completely independent of `x`. So modifying `x` will have absolutely no effect on `r`.

In a sense, reference are "kind-of" syntactic sugar for pointers, although not really the same, as you cannot have an uninitialized reference.