# Difference between `import` and `#include`? cpp20

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I don't understand why

1. I saw `import std.core;` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/import-export-module?view=msvc-160)
2. I can't `import std;`
3. I can't `import std.iostream;`
4. I can `#include <iostream>`

Can you explain why above is happening? Maybe i guess `std.iostream` is not a module. Then why `1.` works?

@Someprogrammerdue provided [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) reference, and its says

```
import <iostream>;         // import declaration
```

When I run following in my compiler

```
import <iostream>;

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

I get

```
main.cpp:1:8: error: 'iostream' was not declared in this scope
    1 | import<iostream>;
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ include and import difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172262/c-include-and-import-difference)

Comment: @RohanBari I understand that `#import` was a thing only for `MS`. But my question is about `import` without the `#`

Comment: `import` is new for [*modules*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) which were added in the C++20 standard. If you search for e.g. `c++ modules` you might be able to find more information and tutorials. Of note, `import` is not the same (or even similar) to the preprocessor `#include` directive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I don't understand why
>
> 1. I saw import std.core; here

You saw what you did because you read the page and that's what was written there.

> 2. I can't import std;

This is because the C++20 standard library doesn't define modules. And because no other library can (or shouldn't) define module `std` because that module name is reserved for language implementation / future standardisation.

> 3. I can't import std.iostream;

See 2.

> 4. I can `#include <iostream>`

That header is part of the C++20 standard library.

> Then why 1. works?

The MSVC documentation explains:

> Although not specified by the C++20 standard, Microsoft enables its implementation of the C++ Standard Library to be imported as modules.

P.S. Support for modules is at the moment of writing only partially implemented by all major compilers with the exception of MSVC which appears to have full implementation since 19.28 (the modular standard libary is not a requirement for this).

P.P.S. Modular standard library is planned for C++23.

Answer (score 0):

2. `import std;`

Improvement in compilation time.

According to ISO C++23, there is also `import std.compat;`.

Differences between the two are as follows (extracted from P2465R3):

`import std;` imports everything in namespace `std` from C++ headers (e.g. `std::sort` from <algorithm>) and C wrapper headers (e.g. `std::fopen` from <cstdio>). It also imports `::operator new` etc. from <new>.

`import std.compat;` imports all of the above, plus the global namespace counterparts for the C wrapper headers (e.g. `::fopen`).

`import ...` is said to be much faster to compile than `#include ...`.

[Interview with Bjarne Stroustrup (InfoWorld): C++ 23 to introduce module support](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3662808/c-plus-plus-23-to-introduce-module-support.html).

You can check C++ compiler status here (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). Search 'Standard Library Modules'(P2465R3) in 'C++23 library features' table.

P.S. Modules are not supported fully by most compilers yet. For MSVC users, please, refer to this link.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170).

Comment: You explain why `import` is a fancy tool, but you don't explain his point 2 (why `import std;` fails).

Comment: `import std;` is a C++23 feature and most compilers have not implemented it yet.