# C++11 - GCC - Can #import (used once) replace many #include? (or is that necessary?)

Tags: windows, c++11, gcc, import, include

I was reading at [C++ #include and #import difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172262/c-include-and-import-difference).

It says that `#import` includes a file only if it hasn't been included before.

I have been finding, in some code like OpenCV, the exact same `#include` in many of their files. That repetition did not seem necessary to me. I thought that it would be better to simply use each `#include` only one time in one beginning header collection file. Now, I am reading about `#import`. I am wondering that if every time that `#include` is used, in different files in the same program, for the same header file, that it might cause the code to become larger and the executable to become larger and maybe make a longer compile time.

Example:

- The file1.h has `#include <math.h>`.
- The file2.h has `#include <math.h>`.
- The file3.h has `#include <math.h>`.

If file1.h is used first, then it's `#include <math.h>` should be suffice for file2.h and file3.h.

If file1.h and file2.h and file3.h all have the same `#include <math.h>`, that seems to be placing an extra load on the compiler and maybe worse.

If multiple occurrences of the same `#include` cause problems, then would replacing them all with `#import`?

Can `#import` (used once) replace many `#include`? (or is that necessary?)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You do not seem to have actually investigated the
use of `#import` with GCC/C++11. You should do that and review your question.
Read about [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and
[`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once). You might also
be interested in [C++ keyword: import (since C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/import)

Comment: @Mike Kinghan thank you for the suggestions and links.

Comment: @Mike Kinghan, I received part of an answer to my question in these links, thank you. I received a further and more complete solution to this issue elsewhere outside of these links. Thank you.